# require.js listener or callback

Tags: requirejs

I am loading a 3rd party script that simply creates an overlay on a site it has been loaded onto.  It works fine but sites using require.js seem to have intermittent issues I'm assuming with async loading some js files.  Is there any type of callback or way to create a module in the DOM as sort of a listener to see if require.js is done loading?

I tried this but not even close:

```
  define(function() {
    alert('test');
    return {};
  });
```

and

```
define('myModule',
    function () {
      var myModule = {
        doStuff:function(){
          console.log('Yay! Stuff');
        }
      };
      return myModule;
  });
console.log(myModule);
```

Comment: Neither code snippets are particularly enlightening as to what you are trying to do exactly. Please spell it out.

Comment: I was trying to load 3 javascript files to create an overlay on a 3rd party site using require.js

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a secondary require.config file and loading the module with require if require is detected, seems to work fine.

```
if(typeof require === 'function') {

  var base = 'http://' + someDomainVar;

  function getJSTreeURL() {
    var url = base + '/js/libs/jstree.min';
    return url;
  }

  function getModuleURL() {
    var url = base + '/module';
    return url;
  }

  var reqTwo = require.config({
    context: "instance2",
    baseUrl: "instance2",
    paths: {
      'jq': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min',
      'jqTree': getJSTreeURL(),
      'module': getModuleURL()
    },
    shim: {
      'jq': {
        exports: 'jq'
      },
      'jqTree': {
        deps: ['jq'],
        exports: 'jqTree'
      },
      'module': {
        deps: ['jq', 'jqTree'],
        exports: 'module'
      }

    }
  });

  reqTwo(['require', 'jq', 'jqTree'],
    function(require, jq, jqTree) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        require(['module'],
          function(module) {
            console.log('loaded');
          }
        );
      }, 0);

    });
```